# Terraform module outputs to another module

Tags: terraform

I have the following state, with an inital vpc module. I am trying to pass the vpc id to an instance module to separate out the infrastructure.

```
    terraform state list 
    module.my-vpc.aws_default_route_table.clear-default
    module.my-vpc.aws_internet_gateway.gw
    module.my-vpc.aws_route_table.rt
    module.my-vpc.aws_route_table_association.a
    module.my-vpc.aws_route_table_association.b
    module.my-vpc.aws_subnet.UAT-vpc-subnet1
    module.my-vpc.aws_subnet.UAT-vpc-subnet2
    module.my-vpc.aws_vpc.UAT-vpc
```

Created output - within the root/main tf calling the modules.

```
    output "vpc_id" {
    value = module.my-vpc    ----- attributes do not sem to            work?
     }
```

To pass this on to another module -

```
    module "app" {
    source              = "./modules/app/"
    vpc_id             = module.my-vpc.vpc_id
    }
```

Can not get this to work?
I believe this is the correct output format, can anyone enlighten me otherwise please?

Answer (score 0):

You need first to make output from within your vpc module, and you can't use module keyword there.

So what you need to do is reference the source directly there. For example :

```
output "vpc_id" {
    value = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id 
}
```

Since you are writing this as a part of the vpc module you will have access to vpc id with similar command to this.

Then you can reference that output inside your other module like you wrote :

```
module "app" {
    source              = "./modules/app/"
    vpc_id             = module.my-vpc.vpc_id
}
```

Comment: terraform validate
        Error: Unsupported argument

        on main.tf line 14, in module "app":
       14:   vpc_id             = module.my-vpc.id

        An argument named "vpc_id" is not expected here.

Comment: Frustratingly, the output doesnt seem to output even the values are correct.